# CS50: Recover, images say unsupported format when opening

Tags: cs50, recover

When i run check50 it says images don't match. I have been stuck on this for 2 hours now I don't know what to do. The imaged recover but when i attempt to open it it says thats the file type is not supported. When i run check50 it says images do not match. I dont know what to do. Im new to coding and im still a begginer so i apologise for if this is a stupid question. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512
#define FILE_NAME_SIZE 8
bool is_start_new_jpeg(BYTE buffer[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
    }
FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    printf("File not found\n");
    return 1;
}

BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
int file_index = 0;
bool have_found_first_jpg = false; 
FILE *outfile;
while (fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, infile))
{
    if (is_start_new_jpeg(buffer))
    {
        if (!have_found_first_jpg)
        {
            have_found_first_jpg = true;
        }    
        else 
        {
            fclose(outfile);
        }
        
        char filename[FILE_NAME_SIZE];
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", file_index++);
        outfile = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (outfile == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }    
        fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, outfile);     
               
    }
    else if (have_found_first_jpg)
    {
        //keep writing on the previous file
        fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, outfile);
    }
    
}
fclose(outfile);
fclose(infile);

}
bool is_start_new_jpeg(BYTE buffer[])
{
    return buffer[0] = 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0;
}
```

can someone please tell me where I went wrong. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The messages comes because the first byte of every signature block has been turned to 0xff. There is (likely) a typo in the `is_start_new_jpeg` function.